# Best Route For Input Clocks on Kintex7 FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I'm looking for advice on a less than ideal situation.

I've inherited a project where we have a hardware design issue. We generate a clock to a chip which feeds the clock back in over a none clock-capable input. This works at up to 160MHz but we are looking to increase the clock so I'm researching IO options. This is used to clock 8 parallel data inputs.

Right now the data inputs go through a delay and a IDDR block. The output is fed to a FIFO. Our clock is still routed to a BUFG - so we have:

```
Data - IDELAY - IDDR - FIFO
Clock - BUFG ----^------^
```

I read somewhere that routing to a BUFG has a large delay so a BUFR-BUFIO is better. Is this the case? Have I missed a better option?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming: it is about electronics. It ought to be on the Electronics Stack Overflow site.

Answer (score 0):

When you say generating a clock to "a chip", I will assume that you mean the Kintex7 chip.

The delay is not a problem. The issue is for your timing closure to be set up properly so that the static timing analysis can validate whether you violate any setup or hold time in all boundary corners of the board.

If you look at DS182 document, you will find under AC Switching characteristics which will give you a rough idea on how well the chip can perform.

However, the best is to let the timing analyzer inside Vivado calculate for you whether your desired clock frequency will be able to close timing.

You just need to make sure

1. The data input is synchronous to your final clock.
2. If it isn't, then clock that data input across two stages of registers with respect to the final clock.
3. Specify your timing constraints
4. Run through synthesis and implementation
5. Check the timing to see that there are no violations.

Or maybe I did not understand something about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Regarding your second bullet point, two-register clock domain crossing is only suitable for single-bit data signals. An 8-bit bus as in the question would need something more sophisticated.